# Firebase multiple users logout at the same time in React JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, snapshot

I am the admin in my application. More than ten users can access the user website for my application. When I'm making changes on the admin side of the application, none of the users should be logged in. Suppose, If a user is logged in while I'm making changes on the admin side, if I press a button on the admin side, all the logged in users should be logged out, and after I've made all my changes on the admin side, if I press that button again on the admin side, users can generally access their user side of the application.

[image]

[image]

FrontEnd: React JS
Database : Firebase Firestore

Answer (score 0):

A user that is signed in to your app has an ID token that is valid for up to an hour. Once that token has been created, there is no way to revoke it.

Somehow, you could revoke all users [Refresh Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens), but you would need to wait for an hour until all users’ current ID token has expired.